# Returning a value from a CSV file (jQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I need to create a search function that will return the relevant row of data that is searched from my CSV file. Is this possible in jQuery or javascript?

For example: if the data contains a name column and ratings column...
'Joe - 5', 'Adam - 4', 'Jane - 3'. When you search for Jane it will return '3'.

I've looked at converting into JSON using tools like these - http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm however the CSV file appears to be too large and the application crashes..

Please can somebody show/tell me the best way to approach this.

Comment: How large are these CSVs?

Comment: Very unlikely that it is crashing. Possibly there an error or something did wrong that consumes a lot of memory. Can you post an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: About 74MB - You can download the containing ZIP at the bottom of this page http://www.hefce.ac.uk/analysis/yp/gaps/

Answer (score 0):

You can read file using jquery.

```
jQuery.get('file.txt', function(data) {
   alert(data);
   //process text file line by line
   $('#div').html(data.replace('n',''));
});
```